# Is it possible to call 2 table returning functions in one main wrapper function in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-16

I have 2 functions which perform selects on 2 tables and return data respectively.

These are defined as follows:

`get_table_data`:

```
-- Function that performs a SELECT query on the table and returns the result as a SETOF
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_table_data(uuid);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table_data(sessiontoken uuid)
RETURNS SETOF device
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
        DECLARE user_id UUID;
        DECLARE organisation_id UUID;
BEGIN

    -- Get UserID from User table
    SELECT UserID INTO user_id
    FROM "user"
    WHERE "user".SessionToken = $1;

    -- Get OrganisationID from User table
    SELECT OrganisationID INTO organisation_id
    FROM "user"
    WHERE "user".UserID = user_id;

    -- Now, you can use the variables as needed in the rest of your PL/pgSQL block
    RAISE NOTICE 'UserID: %, OrganisationID: %', user_id, organisation_id;
    RETURN QUERY


    SELECT *
    FROM device d
    WHERE D.deviceid = (Select deviceid from userdevice ud join "user" u on ud.userid = u.userid and u.sessiontoken = $1);


   -- RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM example_table2;
END;
$$;
```

The 2nd function `get_table_data2` is defined as follows:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_table_data2(uuid);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table_data2(sessiontoken uuid)
RETURNS SETOF vwdevicechannel
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
        DECLARE user_id UUID;
        DECLARE organisation_id UUID;
BEGIN

    -- Get UserID from User table
    SELECT UserID INTO user_id
    FROM "user"
    WHERE "user".SessionToken = $1;

    -- Get OrganisationID from User table
    SELECT OrganisationID INTO organisation_id
    FROM "user"
    WHERE "user".UserID = user_id;

    -- Now, you can use the variables as needed in the rest of your PL/pgSQL block
    RAISE NOTICE 'UserID: %, OrganisationID: %', user_id, organisation_id;
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT dc.*
    FROM vwdevicechannel dc
    JOIN
        UserDevice ud ON dc.DeviceID = ud.DeviceID
    LEFT JOIN
        ChannelType ct ON dc.ChannelTypeID = ct.ChannelTypeID
    WHERE
       ud.userid = user_id;
END;
$$;
```

I then want to call this in a main wrapper function called `get_table_data3` defined as follows:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_table_data3();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table_data3()
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
        DECLARE user_id UUID;
        DECLARE organisation_id UUID;
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM get_table_data('151785c6-268f-4893-9d0d-c21079def599');

-- Call the function to get and display the data
    SELECT * FROM get_table_data2('151785c6-268f-4893-9d0d-c21079def599');
END;
$$;
```

I then attempt to call this as follows:

```
select * get_table_data3();
```

But I get the following error:

> [2024-02-08 11:39:57] [42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data
> [2024-02-08 11:39:57] Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
> [2024-02-08 11:39:57] Where: PL/pgSQL function get_table_data3() line 6 at SQL statement

How can I get these 2 functions to execute in 1 function?

I have to do this way because I have a c# executor function which will want to call this 1 main wrapper function `get_table_data3` ?

Comment: What should your function get_table_data3() return? It can return only one result set and it's currently returning VOID. And when you SELECT something inside a function, the result has to go somewhere. That part is also missing in get_table_data3(). Otherwise use PERFORM if you don't need the result

Comment: Is  the goal is to combine and return the results from both get_table_data() and get_table_data2() functions?

Comment: Reading the docs would be a good start: [Returning from function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) or you can go the cursor route [Cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING)  *43.7.3.5. Returning Cursors*.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com Yes the goal is to combine and return the results from both get_table_data() and get_table_data2() functions to be displayed.
So I cant use PERFORM here.

Comment: @ChrisAsi71 Try returning a JSON or concatenated text representation of both result sets, which can be more flexible but requires parsing on the client side. But, if you want to keep the structure and directly return the data as rows, and assuming the structures of device and vwdevicechannel tables are not directly combinable into a single set of rows, you'll need to find a workaround.